# Display formatted text on console using padding

Tags: c#, console-application, padding

I´m planning to write a description of the parameters of my console-app in a formated way similar to the follwoing:

```
The following options are possible:
    myOption:   Text do describe the option, but that should be splitted 
                to several lines if too big. Text should automatically 
                align by a fixed offset.
```

I already got a method to split the text at the right positions (assuming we do not care if we split in the midlle of any word, we would cimplicate things only if we´d care if we actually split at word-boundaries). However I am stuck on aligning the options explanation.

This is the code so far:

```
public void DisplayHelpEx()
{
    var offset = this._options.Max(x => x.ParameterName.Length) + 6;
    Console.WriteLine("The following options are possible:");
    foreach (var option in this._corrections)
    {
        Console.Write((option.ParameterName + ": ").PadLeft(offset));
        WriteOffset(offset, option.Explanation);
    }
}

public void WriteOffset(int offset, string text)
{
    var numChars = TOTAL_NUMBER_CHARS_PER_LINE - offset;
    string line;

    while ((line = new String(text.Take(numChars).ToArray())).Any())
    {
        var s = line.PadLeft(numChars);
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.WriteLine();
        text= new String(text.Skip(numChars).ToArray());
    }
}
```

I have tried many combinations of `.PadLeft` and `.PadRight` but can´t get it to work.

With the approach above I get the following output:

```
The following options are possible:
  myOption: Text do describe the option, but that should be splitted 
to several lines if too big. Text should automatically 
                        align by a fixed offset.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PadLeft takes the text and adds some spaces left or right so that the full text will have a defined width, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx .

However, in your case, you don't want to have the *whole* text to have a fixed width (especially not if you in future want to split nicely at word boundaries), but rather the *offset* at the beginning. So why don't you just add the offset spaces at the beginning of each line, like so?

```
private const string optionParameterName = "myOption";

private const string optionText =
  "Text do describe the option, but that should be splitted to several lines if too big.Text should automatically align by a fixed offset.";

private const int TOTAL_NUMBER_CHARS_PER_LINE = 60;

public void DisplayHelpEx()
{
  var offset = optionParameterName.Length + 6;
  Console.WriteLine("The following options are possible:");
  WriteOffset(offset, optionParameterName + ": ", optionText);
}

public void WriteOffset(int offset, string label, string text)
{
  var numChars = TOTAL_NUMBER_CHARS_PER_LINE - offset;
  string offsetString = new string(' ', offset);
  string line;

  bool firstLine = true;

  while ((line = new String(text.Take(numChars).ToArray())).Any())
  {
    if (firstLine)
    {
      Console.Write(label.PadRight(offset));
    }
    else
    {
      Console.Write(offsetString);
    }
    firstLine = false;

    Console.Write(line);
    Console.WriteLine();

    text = new String(text.Skip(numChars).ToArray());
  }
}

// output:
// The following options are possible:
// myOption:     Text do describe the option, but that should b
//               e splitted to several lines if too big.Text sh
//               ould automatically align by a fixed offset.
```

Note that I used label.PadRight(offset) in the first line to make sure that the string with the label is padded to the correct length -- here the padding is useful because it allows us to make the label string have exactly the same width as the other offsets.

Answer (score 1):

in `WriteOffset` method you do weird things with `text` and it is hard to follow its modifications

test with  a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9JV9g) modified program

```
public class Program
{
    static int TOTAL_NUMBER_CHARS_PER_LINE = 64;

    public static void Main()
    {       
        DisplayHelpEx();
    }

    // i only set test params here
    public static void DisplayHelpEx()
    {
        string ParameterName = "myOption";
        string Explanation = "Text do describe the option, but that should be splitted to several lines if too big. Text should automatically align by a fixed offset";
        int offset = ParameterName.Length + 6;

        Console.WriteLine("The following options are possible:");

        // print caption
        Console.Write((ParameterName + ": ").PadLeft(offset));
        // print help
        WriteOffset(offset, TOTAL_NUMBER_CHARS_PER_LINE - offset, Explanation); 
    }
```

```
    private static void WriteOffset(int offset, int width, string text)
    {         
        string pad = new String(' ', offset);   

        int i = 0;
        while (i < text.Length)
        { 
            // print text by 1 symbol 
            Console.Write(text[i]);
            i++;      
            if (i%width == 0)
            {
                // when line end reached, go to next
                Console.WriteLine();
                // make offset for new line
                Console.Write(pad);
            }  
        }
    }   
}
```