# How to add padding to the left and right of a whole paragraph in C# Console?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-framework-version

I'm having an issue figuring out how to add padding to the whole of a body of text. My code is below.

```
     public static String Format(List<string> list, int leftMargin, int rightMargin)
        {
            // Create an empty string to put the list of words into
            string listTurnedIntoAString = "";

            // Define the type of punctuation that is acceptable for have a space after.
            string punctuation = ".,?!";

            // turn the list of strings into one string
            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                // if we find a punctuation mark remove the space before it
                if (item.IndexOfAny(punctuation.ToCharArray()) == 0 && listTurnedIntoAString != String.Empty)
                {
                    // Remove the space before the punctuation mark
                    listTurnedIntoAString = listTurnedIntoAString.Remove(listTurnedIntoAString.Length - 1);
                }

                // Add the next word to the string. 
                listTurnedIntoAString += $"{item} ";
            }

            // Add padding the left side
            var stringPaddedLeft = listTurnedIntoAString.PadLeft(leftMargin + listTurnedIntoAString.Length);

            // Add padding to the right side
            var stringPaddedBothSides = stringPaddedLeft.PadRight(rightMargin + stringPaddedLeft.Length);

            // Return the formated string
            return stringPaddedBothSides;
}
```

**What I'm Getting:**
[image: Current output]

**Output needed(!):**
[image: What the output needs to be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line has to be parsed individually.

```
public static String Format(List<string> list, int leftMargin, int rightMargin)
        {
            // Create an empty string to put the list of words into
            string listTurnedIntoAString = "";

            // Define the type of punctuation that is acceptable for have a space after.
            string punctuation = ".,?!-;";

            // turn the list of strings into one string
            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                // if we find a punctuation mark remove the space before it
                if (item.IndexOfAny(punctuation.ToCharArray()) == 0 && listTurnedIntoAString != String.Empty)
                {
                    // Remove the space before the punctuation mark
                    listTurnedIntoAString = listTurnedIntoAString.Remove(listTurnedIntoAString.Length - 1);
                }

                // Add the next word to the string. 
                listTurnedIntoAString += $"{item} ";
            }

            // Number of charters between each margin
            int betweenMarginSpacing = rightMargin - leftMargin;

            // Placeholder for the a new formatted string
            string formattedString = "";


            while (listTurnedIntoAString != String.Empty)
            {
                // check if we are close to the end of the list
                if (listTurnedIntoAString.Length > betweenMarginSpacing)
                {
                    // format each line
                    formattedString += $"{listTurnedIntoAString.Substring(0, betweenMarginSpacing).PadLeft(leftMargin + betweenMarginSpacing)}\n";

                    // remove the text from the unformatted string after it has been added to the formatted string. 
                    listTurnedIntoAString = listTurnedIntoAString.Substring(betweenMarginSpacing);
                }
                else // we are at the end of the string
                {
                    // append the rest of the string to the formatted string.
                    formattedString += listTurnedIntoAString.PadLeft(leftMargin + listTurnedIntoAString.Length);

                    // declare the formatted string empty
                    listTurnedIntoAString = String.Empty;
                }
            }

            // Return the formated string
            return formattedString;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the Console.Write part of your program

as is beautifully explained in this issue: [Display formatted text on console using padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775215/display-formatted-text-on-console-using-padding)

you have to declare a max line width, and for each line you write on console, you should write a empty string with length of `leftMargin`